# Where to get Java Runtime Redistributables?

Tags: java, redistributable

Where can I download a redistributable for the following version of the Java Runtime?

```
Java 1.6 Update 29
```

Answer (score 3):

The redistributables for Java are the JRE and the JDK.  You can get them from the Oracle website.  If you want versions other than the most recent, start looking here:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html

I should warn you that Java 6 patch 29 is out of date.  There are more recent Java 6 releases with **important security patches**.  You should probably use the most recent Java 6 that you can get hold of, especially if your JRE / application is potentially exposed to untrusted people ....

Comment: When I go to that page I see `Java SE 7, Java SE 6, Java SE 5, Java SE 1.4, Java SE 1.3, Java SE 1.2, Java SE 1.1`.  Which one of these would be `Java 1.6 Update 29`?

Comment: Java 6 ... then scroll down.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jre-6u29-oth-JPR

Comment: @StephenC: I didn't know that `Java 6` actually means `Java 1.6`. Why do they use this naming convention?

Answer (score 2):

New runtimes could be downloaded directly from Oracle at:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Older ones are found on the archive page:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html

Answer (score 0):

[Google](https://www.google.com) tells me [right here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u29-download-513648.html) for SDK, [or here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre-6u29-download-513650.html) for JRE...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link that answers my question:

http://someslack.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/extract-deb-rpm-bin-files/

To summarize:

1. Down load jre-whatever-linux-i586-rpm.bin from Oracle.
2. unzip jre-whatever-linux-i586-rpm.bin
3. rpm2cpio [rpm file] | cpio -div

### EDIT

Hmmm.  I've had better luck going to directory /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45 on my development system and copying the jre directory from there.